# im not sure if ghusl is required in this situation

Tags: ghusl, waswasa

i woke up for fajr one day, and i didn't feel any wetness or anything that i remember, although when later i was about to make wudu to pray, i noticed a spot on my pants. it examined it and it didn't smell, feel, or look much like i had a wet dream, and it even dried COMPLETLEY after about 10 minutes, which means that it must not be a wet dream.

what i think happened was that i was drinking water and i dropped some on my pants, although im not sure.

i am just a very forgetful person and dont concentrate or remember things well, so im not sure what to do. i know that there is no logical way that it could have had a wet dream, and i probably dropped water or something else happened, but i am still getting waswasah.

please help me i am confused.

Comment: When semen dries it leaves a distinct stain. Water should just disappear without leaving any stain. If you don't remember having a wet dream, and you don't see any stain, then there is no need for ghusl. If you are still concerned then you can do ghusl anyways, its just a bath and is good for hygiene.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaykum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh,

This has happened to me a few times too.

In my case, I wait for the underpants to dry. Whenever, I have ejaculated semen, the patch dries but leaves the material stuck together and much harder than normal so then I perform ghusl.
If the patch dries up and sticks together but isn't as hard as semen, it is most likely madhi (liquid released upon arousal).
If the patch fully dries up with no noticeable evidence, it is most likely water.

Answer (score -1):

Waswasa is thoughts in human mind which may be created by setan.
Islam is very lenient, whenever you are in a doubt you never need to get a bath in this situation. Even if it was a drop of semen, you don't have obligations if you were in doubt. However when something is certain you need to act for that.
Kind regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).